# I can't use off function for click event on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna do openable menu on jquery. I use click methods and It's work but I can't close it. How can I close? Thank you :)

```
$("div#kkayit").on("click", function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
});

$("div#kkayit").on("click", function(){
    $("div#kkayit").off("click");
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "close"?  What specifically are you trying to do?  All this code does is change a background color once and then remove the click handler.

Comment: You should use `toggle` and keep the css properties. Just change the visibility of the menu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `toggle` in jquery:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> HERE Will toggle</p>

<button>Toggle between hide() and show()</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have registered the same event for same selector two times. So I would recommend to use only below code for mentioned selector's click event.

```
$("div#kkayit").one("click", function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 1):

Please try below:

```
$("div#kkayit").on("click", function(event){
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
    event.preventdefault();
});
```

Please let me know if I answered your question or not.

Thanks.
Vinay